# Is molecular/transport beam cloning feasible for a quick reaction team to disasters?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, futurology, earth-like

In Star Trek, the Federation uses a a [Transporter](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transporter_(Star_Trek)) to disassemble the atoms that make up an individual and reassemble the said individual near another transport beam. It has been speculated (at least I heard this on the science channel) that since the computer obviously had to store the information to reassemble this person, it might be an efficient way to clone someone.

In my world, I want my people to use clones of trained professional first responders to handle disasters, and traditional cloning methods would not accomplish this as it would take weeks to months to grow the embryo even with growth hormones, and their minds would not mature at the same rate as their bodies (leading to a toddler in the body of a twenty year old man/woman).

I am thinking of using the transporter method of cloning, which involves copying all of the information in a human body onto a hard drive and having the computer reassemble that person without ever actually disassembling him/her. This would lead to multiple identical copies of the same professional, with the same knowledge and skill sets as the template.

My question is this: **1.) How far off would this kind of technology be, and 2.) What would be implications of this technology be when the clones re entered society after their jobs were done? Or would the government simply exterminate the clones to stop a backlash?**

Note that this is not Earth and takes place on a separate planet.

Comment: Check out [The Queendom of Sol](http://www.wilmccarthy.com/queendom.htm) series by Wil McCarthy. Scenarios like you discussed play a big role in these books and they are 'hard-science-fiction', so excellent and plausible explanations are given for how the machines work. However, his machine works via atomic disassembly/reassembly, adding or removing from the matter stores of the machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How far off would this technology be:**

I am inclined to think that such technology would not be feasible for the foreseeable future. Take a closer look at what's involved in transporter technology:

Physical:

1. Make a nearly instantaneous non-intrusive molecular resolution 3d scan of a large object.
2. Store the location, momentum, and charge, of every molecule for future retrieval.
3. Reassemble the object near-instantly using that data

That is assuming that consciousness/memory is stored solely in finite physical brain states (I guess that's a plausible assumption for sci-fi).

Now, we can do 3d scans of objects, but as far as I know these are either intrusive or have very limited knowledge of inner layers. And even relatively "simple" organs, like the liver, would need to be assembled instantly to prevent damage. Imagine trying to "3d-print" a liquid like stomach acid or the blood stream! And you'd need to assemble many compounds in place from their constituent atoms due to the short shelf life. Memories would have to be stored as ions in precise locations (at precise speeds) within the brain.

**What would happen to such clones**

Assuming you have the level of technology to do those things, I would assume it would be easier to "print" the necessary information into the brain of existing humans (learn while you sleep). But your question is more interesting.

I think one likely scenario is that the clones are transported back into the "Database" and their memories merged (or not) back into the "original". Such beings would not legally exist as distinct entities and would remain the property of their original. Of course, you could end up with a scenario like Calvin and Hobbes.

[image: Why Cloning isn't easy]

Comment: The perpetual reuse of the same atoms to recreate the same organisms is a good idea. I probably never would have thought of it.

Comment: Heisenberg's uncertainty principle? What uncertainty principle? We don't care about no uncertainty principle.

Comment: David Brin's *Kiln People* explores the idea of merging duplicates back into the original, as well as the role of such clones in society. His aren't transporter-clones, though; they're made of living clay.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I see 2 issues right off the bat with this.

The first is that you will need a supply of all the materials needed to 'print' the duplicate person.  Lots and lots of raw materials if you are going to have a bunch of them.

2nd issue is much larger.  What do you do with all these copies after they have done their job?  If you have made an exact duplicate with all their knowledge, thoughts and feelings, you have an actual person, with a past.  So to exterminate them you will be committing murder, possibly on a grand scale, and since you created them to help save lives (first responders etc) this seems extremely wrong.

Now if you leave them, if the original had a spouse, each one of the copies also has a spouse.  unfortunately they are all the same single individual.  Each one would expect to come home to them and how would the spouse be able to tell the difference?  Same with any other people in their relationship circle.

Comment: Maybe someone who dedicates their entire life to being cloned, and therefore has no spouse? It would be confusing for umpteen guys to come home to the same wife.

Comment: John, thank you for your service, it has been invaluable. Now, would you be so kind as to, ... uh, step into the disintegrator chamber?

Comment: There's a sci-fi short story I've heard of where a company invented a "transporter". What they actually invented though was a copier. They would copy the person at the destination and then secretly kill the original.

Comment: @TimB that may be why 'Bones' always hated transporters!  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically in the feasible range, but it's Star Trek technology, nothing we could possibly conceive of now.  Raw material might not be an issue pending how sophisticated this technology is...you might just need matter and the beam rearranges as needed.  Energy consumption of this would be quite high, but in Star Trek you have an abundance of power.

Once again, following the higher tech level, it is feasible to put a timer at the DNA level of this cloned human that puts a relatively quick expiration date...somewhat the the kill switch that can be programmed into a virus.  Every clone gets their week in the sun before a quick degradation to death.  There'll be some morality debates on that, but it'd seem better than executing them.

Comment: I've… seen things you people wouldn't believe… (...) All those… moments… will be lost in time, like (small cough) tears… in… rain. Time… to die…

Comment: `it'd seem better than executing them.`-- It would still be executing them, you are just pulling the trigger well before the time of death. Also biological systems are squishy (making predetermined expiration time unpredictable), and emergency situations are likewise unpredictable. It seems you would have some first responders suddenly drop dead at inopportune times.